# Nuxt Auth Module - Multiple redirect options after logout

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I have a website where the user logs in and then gets access to a dashboard. The user can log in and out from their dashboard as well as from the home page. Now I want that when the user logs out from the dashboard, he gets directed to a different page than when he logs out from the home page. Is this somehow possible with the `auth` module in Nuxt? I haven't found a way so far.

my nuxt.config.js looks like this at the moment:

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      home: "/",
      login: "/"
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: "/api/session", method: "post" },
          logout: { url: "/api/session", method: "destroy" },
          user: { url: "/api/settings", method: "get", propertyName: false }
        },
        tokenType: 'Bearer'
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: '/',
      home: false,
    },
  }
```

And then there is the button from the home page:

```
<span v-if="this.$store.state.auth.loggedIn" class="inline-flex rounded-md shadow">
<button
  @click="$auth.logout()"
  v-scroll-to="'#login'"
  >Logout</button>
</span>
```

and the button from the Dashboard:

```
<button
  @click="$auth.logout()"
>
<span class="font-normal text-sm mt-0/5">Logout</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Please share, if you have found any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nuxt auth module didn't provide multiple redirect options for different scenarios.
but there are two inelegant ways to achieve this:
**Method One: change target redirect url with [onRedirect](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/#onredirecthandler)**
write a plugin `plugins/auth.js` with content:

```js
export default function({ $auth }) {
 $auth.onRedirect((to, from) => {
   if(from === '/dashboard'){return '/another-logout'}
 })
}
```

register the plugin in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
{
  auth: {
    plugins: [ '~/plugins/auth.js' ],
    strategies: {}
  }
}
```

**Method Two: override `watchLoggedIn` logic, add `logoutWith` method**

1. First, disable default watch login:

```js
{
  auth: {
    watchLoggedIn: false, // add this line
    strategies: {}
  }
}
```

2. listen `loggedIn` and extend 'logoutWith' for $auth
   create a plugin `plugin/auth.js` with content:

```js
function routeOption (route, key, value) {
  return route.matched.some((m) => {
    if (process.client) {
      return Object.values(m.components).some(component => component.options && component.options[key] === value)
    } else {
      return Object.values(m.components).some(component => Object.values(component._Ctor).some(ctor => ctor.options && ctor.options[key] === value))
    }
  })
}
export default function ({ $auth }) {
  $auth.$storage.watchState('loggedIn', (loggedIn) => {
    if (!routeOption($auth.ctx.route, 'auth', false)) {
      let redirectKey = loggedIn ? 'home' : 'logout'
      if (redirectKey == 'logout') {
        const logout_type = $auth.$storage.getUniversal('logout_type')
        if (logout_type) {
          redirectKey = 'logout_' + logout_type
          // delete to ensure use only once
          $auth.$storage.removeUniversal('logout_type')
        }
      }
      $auth.redirect(redirectKey)
    }
  })
  $auth.logoutWith = (logout_type, ...args) => {
    $auth.$storage.setUniversal('logout_type', logout_type)
    $auth.logout(...args)
  }
}
```

dont forget register the plugin in `nuxt.config.js`

3. update you `redirect` options and call `logoutWith` in any page:

```js
{
  auth: {
    watchLoggedIn: false,
    plugins: [ '~/plugins/auth.js' ],
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/logout',
      logout_dash: '/another_logout',
      home: '/home'
    },
  }
}
```

in page dashboard.vue:

```html
<button @click="$auth.logoutWith('dash')"></button>
```

By the way, if you want to redirect to another login page based on the  route, maybe method one is more suitable

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simply use `$router.push('/dashboard')`:

```
<button @click="$auth.logout();$router.push('/dashboard')">
    <span class="font-normal text-sm mt-0/5">Logout</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I thought so too, but the redirect `logout: '/'` in nuxt.config.js seems to override the `$router.push('/dashboard')`. But I guess I need that redirect for the "normal" Logout case, where the user is supposed to be redirected to '/'

Comment: I tested this snippet, and it worked for me. User redirected to `/dashboard`. BTW I don't think `Nuxt-auth` provides any feature for multiple redirects for `logout`.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just set redirect to false

```
redirect: false,
```

and manually redirect with router to whatever page you want after logout for different pages

Comment: This answer is really simple and it worked a treat!